# fopen does not return

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I used 'fopen' in a C program to open a file in readonly mode (r). But in my case I observed that fopen call does not return. It does not return NULL or valid pointer - execution gets blocked at fopen call. The patch of file is absolutely correct (I have already verified that) and there is no permission related issues. Can anybody please tell what could be the reason for this kind if behavior. Any kind of help is really appreciable. Is there anything related to gcc or glibc?

**EDIT**

Here is the sample code

```
printf("%s %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
   printf("%s %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
   return;
}
printf("%s %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
```

When I run this code, I only get the first print (before calling fopen) and after that program just halts. So fopen does not complete it's operation. The file is a simple configuration file with '.conf' extension and this file can be opened by all other means like vi, cat etc. There should not be any NFS related issue. Filesystem is ext3.

Thanks in advance,
Souvik

Comment: Post the code. We can't tell without that. Include the parameters (with values) you're passing to fopen.

Comment: if you cannot post ur code pls post a sample code in the scenario !

Comment: please specify also the filesystem's type.

Comment: `If the file has been succesfully opened the function will return a pointer to a FILE object that is used to identify the stream on all further operations involving it. Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.` Does it return a **NULL Pointer**? It's different from just NULL.

Comment: Also let us know what kind of file you're trying to open.  In some scenarios such as working with pipes and fifos fopen may block until the other end has been opened by another process.

Comment: What kind of file is it?  If the target is a pipe (`S_IFIFO` in `stat(2)`) without a writer, the reader will block (see `fifo(7)`).

Comment: Can you open that file using some other means like cat? One more possible reason is that the file is on NFS.

Comment: @Souvik post some info, people are hungry! :)

Comment: @Time Machine: He already stated that the call just blocks.

Comment: @Time Machine: Erm... `NULL` is an alias for a null pointer. No, the two are *not* different.

Comment: Replace printf() with fprintf(stderr,) followed by fflush(stderr), as there may be buffering issues. Just to make sure that it really hangs on that line. It is also worth printing `argv[1]` before fopen(). And lastly, did you try to run the whole thing in a debugger?

Comment: What does running your program with `strace` show?

Comment: @Sergey: `stderr` is unbuffered so flushing it is unnecessary.

Comment: @R.. - I thought so before too until I encountered a situation where Qt's qDebug() would print a message and fprintf() to stderr wouldn't. After looking at qDebug() sources I've found out that it does fprintf(stderr,) followed by fflush(stderr). Go figure. So it's better be safe than sorry, especially in cases like this one.

Comment: @Sergey: Funnily enough, I thought not but on testing it on my Mac I found *for that platform at least*, it is true - stderr did not need to be flushed.

Comment: Only one variable is not shown in the code snippet you give. The contents of `argv[1]`. I recommend you do a `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` and verify there is nothing strange going on with the value being passed to `fopen`.

Comment: may be the file is on NFS system, and network is slow/unavailable.

Comment: @Jeremy, that was some very abnormal situation. Like a program segfaulting immediately after fprintf() or something like that. I don't remember the exact platform, but it was either Linux or HP-UX on RISC. And I don't think Qt does that flush just for fun.

Comment: @Sergey: Well, there's nothing in the POSIX standard that I can find to say that stderr *must* be unbuffered.  That's why I qualified my previous comment by saying it is unbuffered at least on OS X.  I make no claim regarding platforms I haven't tested it on.

Comment: If `cat` can open your file, then there is something wrong with your code. Is your application multi-threaded? Are you certain that the file name is properly passed to fopen()? Unless you post more code or give more information we cannot really tell more.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a few reasons:

- You've corrupted memory somewhere, and all bets are off as to what's happening (run your program through valgrind)
- You're calling this code inside a signal handler, fopen() is not signal async safe, so really anything could happen (a deadlock due to the FILE* internal mutex is common though)
- The file is a [fifo](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo) , in which cases opening the file will block until someone opens the file at the other end(read/writing)
- The file is on a stale NFS mount.
- The file is a character/block special file with semantics that open blocks until something interesting happens,

Comment: Tried the same code on some other PC and it worked fine. Not sure what went wrong with my pc. Anyway, thanks a lot for all the help and suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

So what? fopen is allowed to block until the file has been opened, or until it has been determined that access is denied. If you have a slow storage device, it is absolutely correct to wait until that becomes available. But that is an operating system issue then, not C's.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you don't close the file if you open it successfully.

Is it possible you that you have run it before and killed it, and now you have a process out there which has the file open, and locked?

If so, then maybe fopen is waiting for the lock to be released.

Comment: An interesting thought, but I don't see any locking code there. Even Windows will allow opening a files by multiple processes in readonly mode. This question is tagged Linux, and Linux is even more forgiving in this sense. And besides, he is saying that other programs can open that file.

Comment: Somewhat related: it's possible that some memory corruption has written over the mutex on the open file list lock, causing `fopen` to hang forever in `pthread_mutex_lock` or equivalent. If OP would listen to any of our answers and just run `strace`, this could quickly be confirmed or refuted.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you've redefined a symbol in the reserved namespace: either something beginning with two underscores, an underscore and a capital letter, or any of the standard C library functions? If so, that results in undefined behavior, and  it's possible that `fopen` somehow ends up calling part of your code instead of the correct code in the standard library.

This question has a major "missing information" smell to it. I seriously doubt the code snippet in the question has the behavior OP has described when it appears by itself in `main`, and I wonder if OP hasn't done some bogus stuff he's not telling us about...

Comment: Should be a comment.